# $.datepicker._curInst null when no selecting a date from datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code to move the day in the datepicker using an external button.

```
 function moveDay(n) {
        var date = new Date($.datepicker._curInst.selectedYear, $.datepicker._curInst.selectedMonth, $.datepicker._curInst.selectedDay);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + n);
        $("#txtDateFilter").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date(date));

    }
```

My problem is that if I do not click on the date picker and select a day, the _curInst is null. So, I need to know how to avoid that.

Here is my Datepicker initialization (the defaultDatePickerSetting is just for translations):

```
            $("#txtDateFilter").datepicker($.extend({
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    $("#hdnMes").val(inst.selectedMonth + 1);
                    $("#hdnAño").val(inst.selectedYear);

                }
            }, defaultDatePickerSetting));

            $("#txtDateFilter").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing this line:

```
var date = new Date($.datepicker._curInst.selectedYear, $.datepicker._curInst.selectedMonth, $.datepicker._curInst.selectedDay);
```

to this

```
 var date = $("#txtDateFilter").datepicker("getDate");
```